# How to do a basic left outer join with data.table in R?

Tags: sql, r, data.table

I have a data.table of a and b that I've partitioned into `below` with b < .5 and `above` with b > .5:

```
DT = data.table(a=as.integer(c(1,1,2,2,3,3)), b=c(0,0,0,1,1,1))
above = DT[DT$b > .5]
below = DT[DT$b < .5, list(a=a)]
```

I'd like to do a left outer join between `above` and `below`: for each `a` in `above`, count the number of rows in `below`. This is equivalent to the following in SQL:

```
with dt as (select 1 as a, 0 as b union select 1, 0 union select 2, 0 union select 2, 1 union select 3, 1 union select 3, 1),
  above as (select a, b from dt where b > .5),
  below as (select a, b from dt where b < .5)
select above.a, count(below.a) from above left outer join below on (above.a = below.a) group by above.a;
 a | count 
---+-------
 3 |     0
 2 |     1
(2 rows)
```

How do I accomplish the same thing with data.tables?  This is what I tried so far:

```
> key(below) = 'a'
> below[above, list(count=length(b))]
     a count
[1,] 2     1
[2,] 3     1
[3,] 3     1
> below[above, list(count=length(b)), by=a]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found
> below[, list(count=length(a)), by=a][above]
     a count b
[1,] 2     1 1
[2,] 3    NA 1
[3,] 3    NA 1
```

I should also be more specific in that I already tried `merge` but that blows through the memory on my system (and the dataset takes only about 20% of my memory).

Comment: Can you just write in human terms what you want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: You could have tried looking for the answer first. a data.table is an extension of data.frame, and has a merge function.

Comment: Agree you should explain what you want in natural language, but in addition I get an error in both version 1.6 and (after updating) 1.6.4: Error in abs(j) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(j) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Comment: Sorry, it was late - hopefully the question is a gazillion times better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this is giving you something useful. Your example is too sparse to let me know what you want, but it appears it might be a tabulation of values of `above$a` that are also in `below$a`

```
table(above$a[above$a %in% below$a])
```

If you also want the converse  ... values not in `below`, then this would do it:

```
table(above$a[!above$a %in% below$a])
```

And you can concatenate them:

```
> c(table(above$a[above$a %in% below$a]),table(above$a[!above$a %in% below$a]) )
2 3 
1 2
```

Generally `table` and `%in%` run in reasonably small footprints and are quick.

Comment: This doesn't give me the `a`s with 0 counts, though, which is why I wanted a left outer join.

Comment: Yes it does. The "zero counts" are 2 "3"s from the !x %in% y indexing. If you wanted to label them as such you could insert an additional named value between them: `zeros->`=0,

Answer (score 4):

Since you appear to be using package `data.table`: check `?merge.data.table`.
I haven't used it, but it appears this might do what you want:

```
merge(above, below, by="a", all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

Comment: In fact merge is base function and works also for data.frames.

Comment: @mbq: `merge.data.table` is really quite different than `merge.data.frame`.

Comment: @DWin Ok, but nevertheless one does not need data.tables to get merge functionality.

Comment: @mbq. That is correct... BUT if one is using data.table objects then one does need to know the proper syntax to achieve one's goals, and that can only be gathered from ?merge.data.table and not ?merge.data.frame.

Comment: works if the by column is uniquely valid, but this is not always be the case in a left join

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easier:

```
setkey(above,a)
setkey(below,a)
```

Left outer join:

```
above[below, .N]
```

regular join:

```
above[below, .N, nomatch=0]
```

full outer join with counts:

```
merge(above,below, all=T)[,.N, by=a]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `above[below, .N]` just give you back the total number of rows, due to the `.N`?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a way to do this with `data.table`, which I felt is more natural for me to understand than DWin's `table`, though YMMV:

```
result = below[, list(count=length(b)), by=a]
key(result) = 'a'
result = result[J(unique(above$a))]
result$count[is.na(result$count)] = 0
```

I don't know if this could be more compact, though. I especially wanted to be able to do something like `result = below[J(unique(above$a)), list(count=length(b))]`, but that doesn't work.